# PostgreSQL force X amount of foreign key rows after insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE projects
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
);
INSERT INTO projects (name) VALUES ('Portfolio Website'), ('Client Website');

CREATE TABLE developers
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
);
INSERT INTO developers (name) VALUES ('Kevin'), ('Mark'), ('Simon');

CREATE TABLE languages
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
);
INSERT INTO languages (name) VALUES ('HTML'), ('PHP'), ('ASP.NET'), ('Java');

CREATE TABLE developer_languages
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    developer INTEGER REFERENCES developers(id),
    language INTEGER REFERENCES languages(id)
);
INSERT INTO developer_languages (developer, language) VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,3), (3,4);

CREATE TABLE project_developers
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    project INTEGER REFERENCES projects(id),
    developer INTEGER REFERENCES developers(id)
);
```

The requirement is that every project has a HTML developer and a Java developer. Is there any way to create a rule that enforces this?

I know I could just have a 'html_dev' and 'java_dev' column in the projects table but this then is an extra data source if you wanted to get every developer on the project stored in these two columns and the project_developers table.

I hope my question makes sense? I'm not even sure where to start looking so I though someone might be able to point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Use a deferred constraint trigger to check the constraint at commit time.

Comment: Would you mind providing the SQL? I have googled deferred constraint trigger but I don't quite understand how it works... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify also, I would like this to be checked on insert of a new project, update and delete of a project developer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not easily solved and a constraint trigger is not the solution because you cannot create a constraint to match your problem. One solution is the following, although it is a bit artificial:

1. Remove the INSERT privilege from the projects table.
2. Create a function insert_new_project(nm text, html_dev integer, java_dev integer) which inserts the new project and two inserts in project_developers. Check that the developers indeed have the required language skills.
3. Remove the UPDATE privilege on project_developers. Create a BEFORE DELETE trigger on project_developers to check that if you delete a Java or HTML developer from a project there is at least one such developer remaining. (So if you want to remove a developer, first insert a replacement.)

This procedure ensures that a new project has one developer of both flavours and that when developers get removed from a project at least one of each flavour remains. Insert a new project with `SELECT insert_new_project('New project', 1, 3);`.